# ANY/ALL (array) error upgrading from SQLA 0.6 to 0.7 (or anything higher)

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm attemping to upgrade from using SQLAlchemy 0.6.5 to 0.7.8 or higher and using postgres9.2 and am now receiving the following error:

> `<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError'>` (ProgrammingError) op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side

```
SELECT a.attname  
FROM  pg_class join pg_index ix on t.oid = ix.indrelid
join pg_attribute a on t.oid=a.attrelid and a.attnum=ANY(ix.indkey) 
WHERE t.oid = %(table_oid)s and  ix.indisprimary = 't'
ORDER BY a.attnum\n        " {'table_oid': 17143}
```

This is an internal transaction to SQLAlchemy so I don't what about my query or schema is causing it.  Maybe a switch I'm missing since it doesnt' like indkey, which is a vector?

Comment: `pg_index.indkey` is an `int2vector`. I'm a little surprise this doesn't work, as they're generally treated as arrays. E.g. `SELECT 1 = ANY(indkey) from pg_index` works. What happens if you run that statement, after substituting the table oid in, by hand?

Comment: is this Postgresql 9.2?   that error is something we get on Amazon Redshift, it's an issue specific to them.

Comment: I've tried PG 9.2 and 9.0 - same error.  And the original SQL noted in the exception doesn't run (what is table t????) - I needed to add an alias for pg_class as table t:  SELECT a.attname  FROM  pg_class t join pg_index ix on t.oid = ix.indrelid join pg_attribute a 
 on t.oid=a.attrelid and a.attnum=ANY(ix.indkey) WHERE t.oid = 17143 and  ix.indisprimary = 't'
 ORDER BY a.attnum       Then it runs without error.

Comment: So it turned out to be one of the systems I was connecting to was still running and older Postgres 7.   That apparently isn't supported by anything newer than SQA 0.6 , tho I couldn't find any info in the docs.

Comment: this is an error that would only occur on redshift or Postgresql prior to version 8.1 (and am still trying to find a way to fix it).   can't see why you'd get it on PG9.